# Ubuntu MySQL not starting?

Tags: server, 16.04, mysql

Okay, I've been working on trying to find a fix for this but whenever I type "service mysql restart" or "service mysql start" I am returned with this error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Once performing the command "systemctl status mysql.service" I get this:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled
Active: activating activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-08-08 21:30:55 CEST; 15
Process: 17334 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 17332 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0
Main PID: 17334 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 17335 (mysql-systemd-s)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
       └─control
         ├─17335 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
         └─17450 sleep 1
```

Now I'm no genious when it comes to ubuntu so I literally have no clue what's going on here which is really awkward....

I'm also going to post the journalctl -xe if that's any help :)

```
Aug 08 21:45:09 serenitypvp systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 08 21:45:09 serenitypvp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 08 21:45:09 serenitypvp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 08 21:45:09 serenitypvp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and looked into `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, then discovered I used an invalid variable name (so, in my case, the error was `[ERROR] unknown variable 'mywrongvar=value'`)